# What does a XAML app workflow look like

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've been trying to find how does the lifecycle of an application with a GUI written in XAML looks like. [This blog post](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/04/03/optimize-startup-time.aspx) really confused me. The quote:

> To fully understand the areas of opportunity for improving startup time, it's important to understand the workflow of a launching application.

```
1. The App constructor is called in App.xaml.cs.
2. XAML in App.xaml is parsed.
3. Application_Launching is called in App.xaml.cs.
4. The Page constructor of your MainPage is called.
5. XAML in your MainPage is parsed.
6. OnNavigatedTo is called in your MainPage.
```

I though that XAML is compiled to BAML and embedded to dll. Runtime just translates BAML to .Net objects.

Is it different for WP7 Silverlight? Does Runtime parse it like a browser parses HTML?
What is the point of C# files generated from XAML? (e.g. Main.xaml.g.cs) Is it different for C++ and XAML apps?

Answer (score 2):

`.g.cs` files are auto-generated and contain information related to the general layout of a XAML page. [Here is a pretty good description](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/16906.aspx).

The runtime indeed parses the XAML that is embedded in the assembly - unlike WPF, it is not embedded as BAML.

Comment: This design is really surprising. SL for WP7 works in a very limited environment and it seems to be the first candidate for XAML compilation.