# When I build a Silverlight project, what happens to XAML files?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, build

Can you please explain the life-cycle of an XAML file in terms of compiling?

When I build a Silverlight project what happens to a XAML file in the build process?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035611/what-does-a-xaml-app-workflow-look-like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer about the intermediate .g.cs file by Jon Skeet (*now deleted, but that part quoted below for context*) was partly correct but did not answer your actual question in full:

> JS: An early part of the build process creates a Foo.i.g.cs file in the
>   obj directory containing a partial class, and that gets compiled in
>   the normal way along with your own .cs files.

The .g.cs files contain pieces missing from the code-behind required to connect named elements to class members during `InitialiseComponent()`. e.g. this is from a basic MainPage.g.cs:

```
public void InitializeComponent() {
    ...
    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/SilverlightApp1;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
    this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
}
```

This is bit like the designer files generated for WinForms controls/dialogs, but happens at compile time instead of design time.

- The compiler parses to validate the XAML and to determine what named elements need to be generated (into the partial class).
- The XAML file itself gets stored as a resource in the DLL during the build (in the example above it is stored as `"/SilverlightApp1;component/MainPage.xaml"`)
- Note: For WPF only, the embedded XAML file is actually converted to a more memory-efficient binary version referred to as a BAML file.

Answering your comment to Jon Skeet (now deleted), you are partially correct in asking:

> So parsing the whole XAML document -all the elements, attributes etc.-
>   is not part of the WPF or SL builds? Am I correct?

Aside from the parsing mentioned above, for validation and named elements, the rest of the parsing (of the element tree and templates etc) is actually *done at runtime* when `LoadComponent()` effectively deserializes the XAML and creates a visual tree of elements you authored.

Comment: Thanks indeed for the explanatory answer!

Comment: @pencilCake: A very good reference. Not seen that one before (mainly as I do 100 times more Silverlight than WPF work). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you build a Silverlight project a .xap file is created, this is basically just a .zip-file with another extension, containing an AppManifest.XAML and your project in a DLL-file (together with DLL:s for other dependencies).

If you run the DLL through dotPeek or Reflector you'll see that the XAML-files you created are found intact in the resources of the dll.